# Query: Find most recent 5 posts from distinct users

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say that we have a `users` table, and a user can have many `posts` (`posts` have the `user_id` column).

I want to retrieve posts for the first 5 users, but only one post per user. So, at the end I want to have 5 posts, where each post belongs to a different user. How can I do that in SQL?

Comment: By "first 5 users", do you mean the users with the five lowest `user_id`s (0-4; 1-5; 1,3,4,5,8; or whatever they happen to be)?

Comment: `select` with a `join` and some distinct/grouping magic.

Comment: PostgreSQL. The ordering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two tables

```
Table : users ; Columns : users_id , user_name
Table2: posts ; Columns : post_id , post_description , users_id
```

And now to retrieve all user with one post for each

```
SELECT * FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1)  as p on p.users_id = u.users_id
LIMIT 5 ORDER BY ASC
```

If you want to get the oldest post for each user

```
SELECT * FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MIN(post_id) as post_id , 
        post_description , 
        users_id  FROM posts
    )  as p on p.users_id = u.users_id
LIMIT 5 ORDER BY ASC
```

And for latest post use MAX(post_id) instead of MIN(post_id)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you:

```
select * 
  from users u
  join posts p on p.idUser = u.id
               and p.id = ( select max(id) from posts where p.id=u.id ) 
 ORDER BY i.id LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the latest five postings (assuming a higher ID post is "newer"), forcing each result to be from a different user.

```
SELECT p.user_id, MAX(p.post_id) AS post_id 
FROM posts AS p
GROUP BY p.user_id -- get unique users
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC -- sort results by post_id number, descending
LIMIT 5
```

With this method, if you need to load other user or post data, it would be best to load it separately after you get the desired user ids and post ids.